# Getting world position from InverseViewProjection gives inaccurate results

Tags: matrix, hlsl

I am trying to implement some volumetric effects inside a triple A game as a modification.
I am getting a ray direction for raymarching using the following technique:

```
uv.y = 1-uv.y;
float2 p = uv * 2 - 1;


float4 scc = float4(p,0.0,1.0);
float4 wc = mul(scc, inverseView);
wc /= wc.w;
float3 rd = normalize(wc.xyz - ro);
```

where inverseView is the WorldInverseViewProjection matrix.

Problem is that the further the camera moves from the world origin, the more stuttering occurs. It feels like float imprecision.

I also tried this method:

```
float4 DepthToViewPos(float depth, float2 texCoord){
    float x = texCoord.x * 2 - 1;
    float y = texCoord.y * 2 - 1;

    float2 screenSpaceRay = float2( x / mProjection[0].x, y / mProjection[1].y);
    screenSpaceRay *= depth;
    float4 pos = float4(screenSpaceRay, depth, 1.0);
    
    return pos;
}

float3 DepthToWorldPos(float depth, float2 texCoord){
    float4 pos = DepthToViewPos(depth, texCoord);
    pos = mul(pos, viewInverse);
    
    return pos.xyz;
}

float3 wPos = DepthToWorldPos(depth, uv);   
float3 raydir = normalize(cameraPos - wPos.xyz);
```

where mProjection is the Projection matrix and viewInverse is InverseView matrix.

However the resulting image stretches weirdly and the directions flip as I rotate across the axies.

As an artist rather then programmer I am lost, could anyone, please, guide me through this? Thank you!

Comment: Kind of a wild guess, what if you do `float3 rayOrigin = mul(float4(p,0.0,1.0), inverseView).xyz; float3 rayDir = normalize(mul(float4(p,1.0,1.0), inverseView).xyz - rayOrigin);`?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, unfortunately that doesnt seem to be it.